# Bootstrap Content not full screen on Mobile phone screen

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

In this Form content not stretch into full screen in the Mobile phone screen but in the computer and Tab screen its show properly. pls advice to solve.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-6 ftco-animate">
        <div class="blog-entry align-self-stretch d-flex">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text p-4 d-block">
                <h3 class="heading mt-3"><strong>Login to the Website.</strong></h3>
                <form id="logging" name="logging" method="POST" action="<?php echo 
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label> Email </label><span class="required text-danger"> *</span> <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label> Password</label><span class="required text-danger"> *</span><input type="password" id="pw" name="pw" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div><small class="text-primary"><a href="contact.php" data-toggle="modal" data- target="#modalAppointment"><span>Forget Password...</span></a> </small></div>
                    </br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="LogIn" id="LogIn" value="LogIn" class="btn btn-primary 
    py-3 px-5">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in which device u r testing..

Comment: @Amaresh on my mobile phone.. ..please chek live site for this issue on your mobile device https://www.ejobs.lk/postjob.php

Comment: check out my answer @Gayan Chaturanga

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove width on `.blog-entry .text`

```
.blog-entry .text {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 55%;/*Remove this Width*/
}
```

OR

Remove this class `text`

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 text p-4 d-block">
```

to

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 p-4 d-block">
```

Comment: no, it's not worked..box size-changing according to screen size but not contents of the box.

Comment: Did you check the Live site for this issue? it still not solve..https://www.ejobs.lk/postjob.php

Answer (score 0):

In .blog-entry .text class remove width property.

In your style.css file .blog-entry .text class is located at **line no. 2764**

```
.blog-entry .text {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    /* width: 55%; */  --- /*remove this width */
}
```

[image]

Comment: @GayanChaturanga my answer is correct check properly

Comment: u have accepted the same answer(ie) width on the class .blog-entry .text, first I only answered to u r question correctly @GayanChaturanga

Comment: Thax for the support after delete width:55%  problem not solved but delete 'text' worked for me ...Thaxxx again both of you..